# google api key as a variable

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$.get('http://localhost/ajax_send_key.php',function (data){
    api_key = data;
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= - my api key - &libraries=places">
// this one work

// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={api_key}&libraries=places">
// Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError

// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + api_key + "&libraries=places">
// TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Autocomplete') at initialize

</script>

<script>
lat = '';
function initialize() { // google places wohl für ortseingabe und dann vorschläge
  var input = document.getElementById('in');
  var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
       var place = places.getPlace();   
       var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    });     
    return (lat);
}   
window.addEventListener('load', initialize);
</script>

<html>
input
<input id='in' type = 'text' STYLE = 'width: 220px' ;></input>
</html>
```

hello,

I have a problem with my Api Key, when I try to use it as a variable. how do I put it into the src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
It works if it is not a variable.

thanks georg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the script tag on load. Wait for the key response to come back first before creating it, and then you can create the `src` appropriately. You'll also have to wait for Google's script to load before calling `initialize`.

```
$.get('http://localhost/ajax_send_key.php',function (data){
    const script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${data}&libraries=places`;
    script.addEventListener('load', initialize);
});
```

Comment: hello CertainPerformance, I think it will work. I change the ` and put it to the end of the line. thank you very much. georg